# How to get probabilities when using Pytorch's densenet?

Tags: deep-learning, probability, pytorch

I want to do a binary classification and I used the [DenseNet](https://pytorch.org/docs/0.4.0/torchvision/models.html#id5) from Pytorch.

Here is my predict code:

```
densenet = torch.load(model_path)
densenet.eval()
output = densenet(input)
print(output)
```

And here is the output:

```
Variable containing:
54.4869 -54.3721
[torch.cuda.FloatTensor of size 1x2 (GPU 0)]
```

I want to get the probabilities of each class. What should I do?

I have noticed that `torch.nn.Softmax()` could be used when there are many categories, as discussed [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-extract-probabilities/2720).

Comment: Have you tried using softmax for that already?

Comment: Thx for your reply! I tried it and it give out two float that adding up to 1. But I'm not sure it's ture or not

Comment: Can you edit your post with the additional information of a `print(model)`, so we can see what the last steps in the model are? If there already is a softmax built into it, it doesn't make sense to redo it, but oftentimes this is instead left open to the user when retraining. Edit: When loading it with `densenet = torchvision.models.densenet121()`, it doesn't. So unless you specified something else, you can safely use Softmax on that.

Comment: Yes, its' last layer is a: (classifier): Linear (1920 -> 2).  And thx for your help :) . I think I should learn deep-leaning first before I use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
import torch.nn as nn
```

Add a softmax layer to the classifier layer:
i.e. typical:

```
num_ftrs = model_ft.classifier.in_features
model_ft.classifier = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, num_classes)

 updated:

model_ft.classifier = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(num_ftrs, num_classes), 
nn.Softmax(dim=1))
```